# Write tab separated csv file in c#

Tags: c#

I am currently developing an application in C# where I need to write a tab separated CSV file from the data that it retrieves from a MySQL Database. The database retrieval works fine.

The problem that I am having is writing the file. Between each variable that I am writing I am using the \t which I thought put a tab into the csv, therefore when opening in excel each variable will be in its own cell.

However for some reason it is not doing this it just writes the whole line as one long string. Below is an example of the code that I am code that I have written:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    int bankID = reader.GetInt16("ban_bankID");
    int userID = reader.GetInt16("ban_userID");
    string bankUsername = reader.GetString("ban_username");
    string accountName = reader.GetString("ban_accountName");
    string accountType = reader.GetString("ban_accountType");
    decimal overdraft = reader.GetDecimal("ban_overdraft");
    char defaultAccount = reader.GetChar("ban_defaultAccount");

    string line = bankID + "\t" + userID + "\t" + bankUsername + "\t" + accountName + "\t"
              + accountType + "\t" + overdraft + "\t" + defaultAccount + "\n";

    tw.WriteLine(line);
```

Thanks for your help with this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format is correct, a CSV expects the file to be COMMA Separated. When saving a Tab delimited file, typically just a txt extension is used (or some people save as .tsv) etc.

If you look at the Save As options in excel the option is Text (Tab Delimited) .txt

If I open the output generated by your sample code (stubbing in the data) everything loads in to Excel 2007 as you would expect.

Comment: +1 I was staring at this question thinking, "there's nothing wrong with that output; it has to be how it's being loaded", but totally missed that the question mentions CSV file yet separating with tab.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your encoding.
You don't show your `TextWriter` instantiation, but it should look something like this:

```
TextWriter tw = new Stream(filename, false, Encoding.ASCII);
```

Comment: Also, be careful with CSV-into-Excel thing, especially with bank account numbers, since if a number exceeds 15 digits, Excel will treat/show it as if it were scientific notation (exponential).

Comment: Use this instead: `var tw = new StreamWriter(filename, false, Encoding.Unicode)`

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Text Import Wizard: Data / From Text.  From there you can specify your delimiter to a tab.

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work. The purpose of the CSV file being written is to allow the user to be able to backup their data from the database to the csv file. Therefore my program reads through the database line by line to write the data to the csv file.

Comment: Since your .csv file is not really "comma"-separated, you have to somehow tell Excel that your delimiter is actually a "tab". If you do this, you'll see your file imports properly. Instead of delimiting by tab, try delimiting by a comma.